# ExtJS could not load data to grid from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I'm a newbee in ExtJS and I have a problem with loading data to grid from JSON file.

Here's my code:

Model:

```
Ext.define('EXP.model.EXT.EXTModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'id'}, 
    {name: 'name'},
    {name: 'email'}
]
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('EXP.store.EXT.EXTStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeId:'EXTStore',
model: 'EXP.model.EXT.EXTModel',
autoLoad: true,

proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: 'data/users.json',
reader: {
type: 'json',
root: 'users',
successProperty: 'success'
}
}
});
```

View:

```
Ext.define('EXP.view.EXT.ComponentsField' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.componentsfield',
title: 'All Users',
store: 'EXT.EXTStore',
initComponent: function() {
this.columns = [
{header: 'Id', dataIndex: 'id', flex: 1},
{header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1},
{header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1}
];
this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

JSON File:

```
{
  "users": [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Ed", "email": "ed@sencha.com"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Tommy", "email": "tommy@sencha.com"}
  ]
}
```

Do I need something more to display this data? I've red a couple of topics about my issue, but none of them was helpful. :(

I haven't any errors in the console. Grid is displaying, but it have no data in it.

Comment: Looking through the code I can see some typos straight away. `AutoLoad` (case). `successProperety` (spelling). The store id for the grid doesn't match.

Comment: I've corrected this mistakes, but it still doesn't work

Comment: storeId still doesn't match `EXT.EXTStore !== EXTStore` also, the store is auto created only if it is listed in Application.js or in a Controller `stores:[]`, otherwise you need to create it manually.

Comment: My Store is creating properly (data is displayed) when I create my data Store locally, like data: [ { id: 1, name: 'ed', email : 'ed@com' } ] instead of proxy : { ... }. However, if I change EXT.EXTStore to EXTStore, nothing is loading. 
Now I change some pieces of code and I have 404 error - file not found.

Comment: Everything is working now. I have this spelling mistakes which you mentioned and a bad file path. Thanks for support :)